# Discord.py how could you edit an attachment such as a txt file and get the bot to send it back

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to copy one's files content into another but nothing I've tried seems to work

EDIT:

ive got this it seems to fail at the end but no errors

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def CopyBypass(ctx):   
    audio_to_bypass2 = str(requests.get("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/707643241700261970/707672527950053406/AK-47_sound.ogg"))
    try:
        attachment_url = ctx.message.attachments[0].url
        audio_to_bypass = str(requests.get(attachment_url))
    except:
        audio_to_bypass = "none"
    if audio_to_bypass == "none":
       await ctx.send("Send your audio file dum dum")
    else:
      with open(audio_to_bypass2, "ab") as rf:
        with open(audio_to_bypass, "rb") as wf:
          for line in wf:
            rf.write(line)
            embed = discord.Embed(
              embed = discord.Embed(title="TEST", description="TEST", color=0xFF0000))
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

right round at the end it says nothing but when I print it doesn't say anything 
either

Comment: it looks like you're reading from strings, not files.

Comment: oohhhhhhhhh tysm